# How to measure an object's real size on the image?

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have a picture of a melanoma. I need to calculate its real size (e.g mm^2). Any ideas how to this? Or, how many pixels are in 1 mm^2?

Comment: That totally depends on the resolution of the camera and the lens used to take the picture. Your question can't be answered as is.

Comment: is there anything else in the image of a known size to use as reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to know the distance from the camera to the object, the focal length of the lens, and the pixel spacing of the imaging sensor (or the size of the sensor in both mm and pixels).  Or you could put a calibration measure (such as a ruler) next to the object at the same distance.

If you don't have those, a lady bug and an elephant could take up the exact same number of pixels, so the answer could be almost anything.

Comment: I'd suggest using a dime or something circular as a calibration object. That way, couldn't you also correct for a slightly off camera angle?